# How to prevent file system manipulation by an User

Tags: php, heroku, permissions, sandbox

#### Information

I have a phpfiddle application in Heroku where an user can play with any php code.

Basically this is the application structure (sample):

```
/app/
|
|--fiddle/ <-- contains all php fiddles generated by the user.
|  |
|  |-- abcde/ <-- random directory.
|      |
|      |--index.php <--- custom user code.
| 
|--app.php <--- entry point and main app file.
```

The user can have many phpfiddles in their account, each of them corresponding to *a random directory* and the `index.php` file is executed through an `<iframe>` later.

#### Question

How to avoid any app user can Create/List/Delete any file/directory outside their random directory through `index.php` file?

#### Research

My current solution was to parse the PHP user code (before execute it) and detect all possible functions like `file_put_contents()`, `unlink()`, `mkdir()`, `dir()`, `rmdir()` and others, but that limits the *scope of the test* and I need the user can play with *these* functions inside their *context*.

I'm afraid that I need to set specials permission to the file system "dynamically" base on resource execution (I guess). How to do that? It's possible achieve that?

**EDIT:** Currently [php.net/runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) does not support PHP 7 yet (https://github.com/zenovich/runkit/issues/87) which is required in this case.

Comment: You may want to look into http://www.php.net/runkit & sandboxing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Realistically, no.** The security implications of running a service such as this where you would execute untrusted third party code is something that requires a lot of technical planning and infrastructure.

To understand the magnitude of the problem, there is a company that provides such a service (ideone.com, no affiliation). It's parent company Sphere Engine offers this as a service to run untrusted code in a secure environment.

Especially running on Heroku, your service would likely give you a lot of headache if it were to be maliciously used (e.g. sending bulk SPAM using PHP's mail(), targeting other users via DoS using PHP's CuRL). These problems would extend past just one user deleting files of another user and would likely get you banned from Heroku. A malicious actor can *and will* figure out ways around your system.

--

To take this a step further, let's consider what you theoretically would need to do to accomplish such a task.

You would begin by using something like Docker, a container that essentially runs like an operating system. You would need to configure the environment so that code running on the container has no internet access, is limited in CPU time, and is destroyed after each code execution.

Every time a user submits code, you would essentially copy the code into the container and allow the code to run. You would then be able to capture the output of the container and return that to the user.

This is a very rough outline of what you would need to accomplish this.

Comment: Even when @2oppin's answer "works", I think your approach is good for secure environments... so I'll take it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "[open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)" PHP setting and wrapp fiddle execution in something like:

```
ini_set('open_basedir', './fiddle');
include('fiddle/fiddle.php');
```

It will forbid fiddles to access file system outside of their folder.

Comment: Nothing prevents the user from resetting that value in the included fiddle with your given solution.

Comment: I've tested this and (for me) it works! Once the value is set, this one doesn't changes in runtime again. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php says "The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending"

Comment: However, nothing prevents me from doing `shell_exec("php my_bypass_file.php")`. That file will not have the `open_basedir` value and would bypass any restrictions imposed in the current runtime.

Comment: @RyanTse, have you tried your example? and what saves you from shell_exec('rm -rf ../../www'), unless correct ownership. functions like this should be disabled in this fiddle approach.

Comment: @Yonel, suggest you to read http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/disable-insecure-dangerous-php-functions

Comment: @2oppin If you look at my answer, I clearly address why this is a security issue that isn't solved with merely an ini_set. That is a extremely simplistic answer that leaves the OP vulnerable to liability and potential damages of third party users and should be avoided.

Comment: Let me make this as clear as possible to anybody reading these answers in the future: **NEVER** attempt to create a system that accepts user input as code and allow it to run haphazardly on your server. Any simple mistake and you will be liable. Next thing you know, you may very well have a lawsuit on your hands or a subpoena asking for information regarding the usage of your server in hacking or accessing illegal content (read: child pornography or worse). Leave making these secure environments to larger corporations or be very well funded to defend yourself in the future.

Comment: @RyanTse, u are really aggressive one))) totally agree with your answer, it seems more secure and convenient, but that doesn't mean  "mere ini_set" can't close most of the holes in "fiddles". You will need to create some secure ini set in container also. and I wonder how you will manage highload of such a resource. How many containers you will need, how many fiddles will be run on each? It's all can be solved, but how many mistakes you will do on the way?

Comment: I'm aggressive in the sense that this is a place where people are here to learn and it's imperative to not appear as if there is a solution to this problem other than proper containerization. There are way too many security vulnerabilities that can exist along the way, especially with the idea of sandboxing. Especially with the fact that OP is building it on Heroku, the chance for error and major problems is high.